# I cannot find boundaries in Divergence and Stokes's Theorems

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I have two questions from my exam. I'm sorry for not remembering what was F.

**1)** $F$ is 3-dimensional vector field. $\delta$ is a surface which is bounded by $z=x^2+y^2-3$ and $z=1$ and oriented in negative $z$

$$ \iint_{\delta}curlF.\hat N.ds $$

Should I do $z=x^2+y^2-3 = 1$ $\Rightarrow$ $z=x^2+y^2=4$ and use polar coordinates?

And I know  we can write $\hat N.ds$ = $\pm \frac{\nabla G}{G_3}dxdy$ when $G(x,y,z)=0$ is equation of surface with (1-1) projection onto a domain in the $xy$-plane. How can I decide what is $\hat N.ds$ when we have two or more equations like $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ and $x+y+z=0$

**2)** It was more confusing me. I have no idea how can I determine boundaries.

I have found $divF=3y$

$$ \iiint_D 3ydV $$

Equations : $z=1-x^2$ parabolic cylinder and $z=0$, $y=0$, $y+z=2$

What should I say for boundaries?

As you can see I have some problems about these theorems. Can someone suggest some tutorials or books etc for catching them pratically?

Thanks

Comment: Try not to ask multiple questions in the same post.  It would better if you split these questions.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question you can simply the Stokes theorem. Indeed that integral is egual to : $$\int_{\alpha} (F,T) $$ where $\alpha =(2cos t, 2sin t, 1)$  with $t = [0,2\pi]$ where $T$ is the tangent vector while $(F,T) $ is the dot product